# Вывод даты в javascript

Tags: javascript

```
function Time() {

 var d = new Date();
 var hours = d.getHours();
 var minutes = d.getMinutes();
 var seconds = d.getSeconds();

 console.log(hours+ ":"+ minutes +":" + seconds);
}

setInterval(Time,1000);
```

данная функция выводит в консоль лог дату и время с новой строки.если поменять console.log на alert, то программа заблочит браузер и будет выводить в окошко дату по 1 секунде.как сделать так,чтобы дата выводилась беспрерывно в html?

Answer (score 2):

```js
const el = document.getElementById('time');
function Time() {

 var d = new Date();
 var hours = d.getHours();
 var minutes = d.getMinutes();
 var seconds = d.getSeconds();

 time.innerHTML = hours+ ":"+ minutes +":" + seconds;
}

setInterval(Time,1000);
```

```html
<div id=time></div>
```